# extend an interface through a function call

Tags: typescript

Context: I'm building an internationalization hook in React with Typescript.

I can't find a way to dynamically add properties to an `interface` or `type` or whatever is needed to make sure my other languages are correct.

Please see my [minimal playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAMg9gYwIYBtoF4oCIIDstQA+2AZgE5YCwAUDQPR311QCSUA7krsFMHFAGc4AWwgALOOyhIAJjN79gYgJYCoAIwgpJUZdwhkSSBNAAUyXBugIxXAOYR5fQSIhK9dqFoEQAlExoIAA8wODIePWADIxNdAEYADlwAFWDgAFkkMCgAbxooAqgAbQBrCBAALkFgMg8AXSqBGo8iKAAxAFdcBGBlOFwAbhoAXwDqBihksWhNbSkBCQ6UeVsAN2guLzIyMME9WKVy6TJoCGEwUGlceQW4JZWkdd5pqFXUDog1PWfoEi6evqWWaSMYIfpNKDkPA2VJBDJZKrKRIpNKZbKYHLDIa0aigSBQACCcmScFh8LABOuACU3B0yLgAPIdYBgZlQTAAHk63RpwDpuAANO1-gSyHYBAA+Uz5XhpRrNXCeYimUxIMUABiq3IQovFvnZEuFPNp9N8AplZUq1VqivN1AK2mQaCq8CdEDtBTV4oA-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).

```js
type Locale = "en" | "fr"

//
// I want to somehow add to this below interface (can be changed to something else)
//
export interface i18nTextMap {
    [key: string]: string | Function;
}
//
// The below should have an error since they are empty and should have the values in the function below
//
const frenchTextMap: i18nTextMap = {};

type AddToTextMapAndReturnOutput = <FuncReturn, FuncArgs>(
  text: string | ((arg0: FuncArgs) => FuncReturn),
  key: string,
  locale: Locale,
  args?: FuncArgs
) => string;


const i18n: AddToTextMapAndReturnOutput = (text, key, locale, args) => {
    //
    //.    ?????  How can I add the key to my interface (or other) as a prop with typeof text, so that my "frenchTextMap" has a typing error?
    //
    const textType = typeof text
    let outputText = text
    //. If french
    if(locale === "fr" && frenchTextMap[key]){
        outputText = frenchTextMap[key]
    }
  
    // Return my output
    if(textType === "string"){
        return text
    }
    // Not part of my question but there shouldn't be an error below
    return text(args)
}


i18n("Hello","hello", "en")     // <= console.log output: hello
i18n( ({name})=> `Greetings ${name}`,"greeting", "fr", {name: "John"}) // <= console.log output: Greetings John
```

You'll notice, and I don't know if this is possible, and I'm open to suggestions, that I'm looking to **add** whatever key is given in `i18n` to my `interface i18nTextMap` (or type or whatever will work) so that if I don't have the right type for `frenchTextMap` it creates an error.

UPDATE

Thanks to @mlegrix, it solved the secondary issue. [Here attached the updated playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAMg9gYwIYBtoF4oCIIDstQA%202AZgE5YCwAUDQJa7ARklILQBiArrggIJkA5gGcoAbxpQpUANoBrCCABcUYcDINBAXRVqNuQQBoaAXwDcNUJCjdeAJQjAuZXFEx7NF2tQZMWbaDoARgAOXAAVCAAPYABZJDAAHj5DACEAPnFJaXlFXXVNHVUCgyIoAApypCEABgB%20FT4ASjdM1KbjahNLcGg%20ABN%208LhImPiwPlx%20hycXAHkuYDBF5LTMzHLsqSYY-P1BMsrqwRrGlvQ2jq2oBWVi-c7pKBREVAgVeGQ0R%20lj4QaoCkaOc2l4aAB6cEQ8FQcIAC2gACMIC8AO6qOFwLgofpQOFIABu0CQrmYZDgZFUDHYUGACJAUGq0AgAFswKBGVMMVicXjCdA6dACaguBBRAxaQioCQeAhgHQ4K5kWjoTQEIq1NKyHgEHDRnEEipgmF9eNErZ%20EJhIYbLKZs5cOtxOYaK7vOrcJrjbhGoNhqaEpNpo4HQslisLQIRDaLfaXE7yjtgDbbjaXl8IDa-iCst4nmhgFAseHgPq3LTosA3U86CRyum3m50JgsOQCAAydtanV6yvjXIgLRNCTUJ5PYvLUuV8vkHsBsADrTXbp56S1xO9OAkIuLSdl5uYADkMt48sVh6gncZVuH1ye2tmrgni31VRvy%20r0gfDp3JbLSFEDwDC8FdVWoSFYSlZU4HRVEeVxZFGUGCBcQlBw2ELdU2UVPBgHFVwWQZZBhEzKBEUWKAACsuE1YA4G5dFBSgGikEECAADowO9cosAACRRF4sEMLAERQQSbRwfAWieCDEkwD1hDgNB2JeA5n2AFRRJeehQlwSoxFwJAWQgEwcwAAwAcW1RxNFEAASAyjJMszhMEaz5QMITSAoG1HOMlQsAAKTgOF8FMqBZPkjUlI41Tf0nFQrIgGyDFEYLQqpXhOG1Xg4SgOhhFwQ9C36CASAYFCgA)

Comment: Does this question depend on React? If so let's tag it as such; if not, could you remove the dependency from the example code?  Also, while it's nice to have an external link to an IDE, it doesn't take the place of having a [mre] as plaintext in the question itself.  Are the errors shown in that sandbox link relevant to your question? If so, can you talk about them? If not, can you edit the example so that it doesn't have any unrelated errors?  I think maybe the idea of "extend an interface through a function call" can be explored without third party dependencies, but maybe you need them.

Comment: The only way this could possibly work as far as I can tell, is if you are modifying the type of an existing object (via control flow analysis... so the function could be an assertion function), and then later in the same scope use the type of that object to define/merge-into the interface in question.  Something like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/weQdYw) shows.  But I don't know how to frame that approach in terms of your i18n stuff without seeing a plaintext standalone minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Anyway, if you want me to write up what's going on in that link as an answer, or if you want to [edit] the example in your question to be a self-contained [mre] and want me to take another look, please mention @jcalz in any reply so that I'm notified.  Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for the feedback. I added some React just to illustrate another type of output, but is indeed not required for my question. Just reformatted and provided a simplified example.

Comment: @denislexic should this  `i18n("Hello","hello", "fr")` throw a type error, considering `frenchTextMap` has no "hello" key? Also could you also add the "wrong" states in the playground.

Comment: @jcalz I think OP wants to do the "opposite" - where they want the declaration of `frenchTextMap` to error if it doesn't contain all the keys used by calls to `i18n` (which I admit is a bit odd to me but understandable).

Comment: @TalgatSaribayev It would be the opposite. The error should be on the frenchTextMap (because it doesn't have the key `hello` that I give when I call `i18n("Hello","hello","fr")`.

Answer (score 0):

In your `AddToTextMapAndReturnOutput` type you are separating the function parameters type from the return type. While the `i18nTextMap` interface is less restrictive since you allow the `Function` type which even if the signature matches, the parameters type and return type are not the same.

A quick solution would be to separate the parameter's type and the return type in both type and interface and making use of Generics like so:

```
interface FuncArgs {
    [key: string]: string,
};
type FuncReturn = string;

interface i18nTextMap<A,B> {
    [key: string]: string | ((arg0?: A) => B),
}
type AddToTextMapAndReturnOutput<A,B> = (
    text: string | ((arg0: A) => B),
    key: string,
    locale: Locale,
    args?: A,
) => B;
```

This way you will have full control on the types of the function parameters and it's return type.

Your code then becomes:

```
const frenchTextMap: i18nTextMap<FuncArgs, FuncReturn> = {};

const i18n: AddToTextMapAndReturnOutput<FuncArgs, FuncReturn> = (text, key, locale, args) => {

    let outputText = text

    if(locale === "fr" && frenchTextMap[key]){
        outputText = frenchTextMap[key]
    }

    if(typeof outputText === 'function' && args){
        return outputText(args)
    }

    return outputText as string;
}

i18n("Hello","hello", "en")     // <= console.log output: hello
i18n( ({name})=> `Greetings ${name}`,"greeting", "fr", {name: "John"}) // <= console.log output: Greetings John since French isn't defined
```

You will notice that we had to cast the return `outputText` since our `outputText` can be a `string` or a `function`. By using union types, typescript cannot infer that our first return statement took care of the latter.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works for the secondary issue I was having, but the main question was to have an error appear on `const frenchTextMap: i18nTextMap = {}`. Any chance you know how to make that happen?

Comment: I've added an updated playground with your part of the solution. The error should show up on line 21

Comment: Not that I know of. The closest I think you will be able to get to, is by using @jcalz recommendation. By using a function which add the property to your key list.
The problem I see, is that since you are using bracket notation to access the key/value pair in the translation object, typescript doesn't infer by default the actual property name, but rather the type the property name.